# Python Split() and re.split()

Tags: python, split, tuples

I'm looking to get a program to read a string/file and display the first three words in it.

So I tried:

```
letter= "a,b,c"
print(letter.split(',')[0])
```

That worked to get one word, but doing [0,1,2] doesn't work as it doesn't accept tuples.

I read about using re.split, but I could only manage this:

```
import re
letter= "a,b,c"
words = re.split((','), letter,)
print(words)
```

That displayed all letters, but I couldn't work out how to only specify 0,1 and 2. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
How can I get it to treat each letter seperate for input into an array? It treats them all as one.

Answer (score 2):

**String split approach**

The `str.split()` returns a list so accessing `[0]` returns the first item of the list. So to access the first 3 item you should use slice

`[x:y]` *x be 0 and y being 3* meaning `x<= range < y` ie `0,1,2` list items

So in your first approach use `letter.split(',')[0:3]`

**Regular Expressions split approach**

The same thing applies using `re.split() function`
It returns the list so you can print the first 3 with `words[0:3]`

Comment: How can I get it to treat each letter seperate for input into an array? It treats them all as one.

Comment: I don't get your point  or you mean something like `x = input()`; `list(x)`@AndrewBlair

Comment: If I have.  x="a,b,c" MyList[] MyList.append(x) print(MyList[1]) it displays "b". If I make x=letter.split(',')[0:3], and then print(MyList[1]) I get an index error.

Comment: You can post another question for that @AndrewBlair

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a tuple, you need a slice.

```
letter.split(',')[:3]
```

Comment: First three words, so it should be: `[:3]`

Comment: if you want to not print a list but CSV you could do `print(', '.join(letter.split(',')[:3]))`